Choosing vectors such that linear combination is nonzero
In one of the steps of a proof that I'm working on I would like to write the following:
Let $a_1, \dots, a_m \in \mathbf{F}$ be nonzero scalars. Choose vectors $w_i$'s ($w_i \neq 0$) from $W \neq \{0\}$ such that $a_1w_1 + \cdots + a_mw_m \neq 0$.
This feels slippery. Is it always possible to find such $w$'s? If so, how to justify this claim?

I suggest:  prove it inductively.  For $m=1$ it's clear, right?  What about $m=2$?

Just to give you an idea for a non-inductive proof: writing $w_i=\frac 1{a_i}\times \vec w$ for some non-zero $\vec w$ does the job unless $m=0\in \mathbb F$.  Not so hard to avoid that problem.

Just to make sure I got it: as for the inductive proof: for $m = 1$ just pick a non-zero $w_1$. Given that for $w_1, \dots, w_m$  we have $u_m := a_1w_1 + \dots + a_mw_m \neq 0$, $w_{m+1}$ can be chosen as $w_{m+1} \neq (-1/a_{m+1})u_m$. Is this OK?

@AJB: That is okay.

Exactly.  Note: I didn't think through a case like the one dimensional space over the field with 2 elements. Might require special pleading.

Yeah,  that one case is bad. There is only one non zero vector so if $m$ is even you can't go it. Only bad case though.

Why not simply choose an arbitrary $w_1\ne0$, and all other $w_i$s $=0$?

@AnneBauval  I took the problem as specifying $\vec w_i\neq \vec 0$ .  As you say, if you allow $\vec w_i=\vec 0$ there's no difficulty, even in the one bad case.

I noticed you did, but as it is, the "problem" does allow $w_i=0$. It only specifies the (obviously necessary) condition $W \neq {0}$.

@AnneBauval  You are right.  I guess I unconsciously figured that the problem was trivial without that restriction so I added it.  It is at least somewhat interesting that you can add it without a problem, save in the one rather special case.

@AnneBauval you're right,  I didn't specify that the vectors should be non-zero. I edited the question

Assuming wlog that $a_1=\dots=a_m=1$, the question boils down to finding (in $W$) $m$ non-zero vectors whose sum is non-zero.

If $|W|\ge3$, choose arbitrarily $w_1,\dots,w_{m-1}\in W\setminus\{0\}$, and then $w_m\in W\setminus\{0,-(w_1+\dots+w_{m-1})\}$.
If $|W|=2$, let $w$ be its unique non-zero vector. Then, $mw\ne0$ iff $m$ is odd.

To summarize: the answer is that it is always possible, except when $W$ is the one-dimensional space over the field with $2$ elements and $m$ is even.
